# How can you remount a local Windows drive under WSL?

Tags: mount, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do I fix this:
[image: Output of df]

and this:

[image: Output of ls -alFh /mnt]

I know I can restart Windows and they'll be back, but they're not listed in fstab, and I can't see how to remount them.

P.S. They are external drives that went off-line during a power hiccup.

Comment: You should be able to simply shutdown WSL then restart it. Are you willing to do that?

Comment: @Ramhound: Trying to avoid it. I have a long-running analysis in one of the open WSL terminals, but it won't be the first time I lose 24+ hours of processing.

Comment: `mkdir /mnt/[new-mount]` `mount -t drvfs [new-mount]: /mnt/[new-mount]` source: https://www.scivision.dev/mount-usb-drives-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Just mount it again using the method for mounting Windows drives not specified in the fstab:

`sudo mount -t drvfs K: /mnt/k`

Done.